# Image restoration: Removing noise and smoothing the outlines

Tags: python, image-processing, computer-vision, image-recognition

I need to restore the tainted image back to original image. Below are the samples of Original image and its tainted(noisy) image.
[image]
[image]

In order to do that here is what i have tried so far and achieved decent output but not so good.

```
    img = cv2.imread(r'D:\Image\tainted.png', 0)

    #Apply morphological closing operation
    #to remove pepper noise
    kernel = np.ones((5,5),np.uint8)
    closing = cv2.morphologyEx(img, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel)

    ret, bw = cv2.threshold(closing, 127, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)

    #Upscale the image and applying blurring operation
    #to smooth the image
    up = cv2.pyrUp(bw)
    for i in range(20):
        blur = cv2.medianBlur(up, 9)

    #downsample the image
    down = cv2.pyrDown(blur)

    ret, bw = cv2.threshold(down, 127, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
```

Below is the output image:
[image: Output Image]

As it can be seen in the output image that there are many zigzags present along the boundary of image, i am trying to remove such zigzags as much as possible.
Is there any way to do the same. 
Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Does that really affect your similarity measure? I wouldn't worry about small deviations and a bit of noise.

Comment: @CrisLuengo in my scenario it effects the contour based local features like curvature, gradient at the corner points. Although i am getting descent results with my current approach but still i want to restore the tainted image to my original image as much as possible. I have updated my exact requirement in the question.